# Stop a loop before a predictable error happens

Tags: c#, wpf, split, textbox

So I need to count lines in a textbox, to do this i use:

```
if (subject.Length <= 20)
{
    bool moreLines = true;
    int onLine = 2;
    int count = 0;

    while (moreLines)
    {
        textBody[count] = TextBox_Text.Text.Split('\n')[onLine];
        Console.WriteLine("Line saved: " + textBody[count]);

        onLine++;
        count++;

        try
        {
            if (TextBox_Text.Text.Split('\n')[onLine] == null)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            moreLines = false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

I insert the split strings into `textBody[]` array but once I approach the last lines where there is no text I want the loop to stop. I tried to do an if statement which checks if the next line is null, and if yes stop the loop. However, I kept getting an IndexOutOfRangeException so I just put the whole thing in a try catch, but I feel like there would be an easier way to do this?

Comment: Because the onLine variable is now past the index bounds. Try, if ( onLine > TextBox_Text.Text.Split('\n').Length) Break;.

Comment: The `TextBox` has a [`LineCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount?view=netframework-4.7.2) property and a [`GetLineText(index)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlinetext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_TextBox_GetLineText_System_Int32_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter ahhh didn't even know that thanks! That fixed the problem I just compare the line count to the onLine and know when to stop :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have over complicated things massively.
The `String.Split` method have multiple overloads, some of them takes as an argument a member of the `StringSplitOptions` enum - one of it's members is called `None`, and the other is called `RemoveEmptyEntries` - so as far as I understand, all you need is this:

```
var textBody = TextBox_Text.Text.Split(
    new char[] {'\n'}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would just to use the following:

```
TextBox_Text.Text.Split('\n').Length
```

The `Length` property returns the length of the array.

Comment: OP said `once I approach the last lines where there is no text I want the loop to stop` - maybe it's better to invoke `Trim()` or `TrimEnd()` before splitting?

Comment: The `TextBox` has a [`LineCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount?view=netframework-4.7.2) property

Comment: i think the problem may be in the [onLine] paramter as it's trying to check the next line for text but next line doesn't even exist in the text box

Answer (score 0):

so I just used the LineCount property instead and done a compare to the onLine

```
if (TextBox_Text.LineCount >= onLine)
{
    moreLines = false;
}
```